# Cloud composer parse json

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have imported a simple json [file into the data folder](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage). What's the best way to load, parse and use params in the json?

Answer (score 1):

The gs://composer-bucket/data folder is fused to Airflow's /home/airflow/gcs/data directory (As specified here https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage#folders_in_the_storage_name_bucket )

If you need to load it in some PythonOperator task definition for example, you could use the very simple following code:

```
import json
with open('/home/airflow/gcs/data/my_file.json', 'r') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
```

This is one way you can do it.

Depending on what you need to load and how you need to use it, you might want to look at Airflow Variables as well instead of a JSON file. (https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#variables)